# Creating a macro for Formatting Cells if "%" symbol found

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to setup a macro which check every cell in a workbook and check if it's a number or a % and change the format of the cell.

My criteria is that if it is a number then it needs to be formatted to:

**_-* #,##0 *-;[Red]* (#,##0)*-;*-* "-"??*-;*-@*-**

And if its a % it needs to be formatted to:

**_-* #,##0% *-;[Red]* (#,##0%)*-;*-* "-"??*-;*-@*-**

Every time i try use it at the moment it comes up with format mismatch code 13 on the % Format.

My code at the moment is:

```
Sub BoldCells()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim thisRow As Long
Dim thiscolumn As Long

'the above declares the last row, this row and this column


lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
thiscolumn = 1

'the above is used to determine what the last row is and this is used for the 
 loop from first cell to last cell

For thisRow = 1 To lastrow

If Cells(thisRow, 1).Font.Bold Then

    If InStr((Cells(thisRow, 1)), "%") > 0 Then

        Cells(thisRow, 1).NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0 _-;[Red]* (#,##0)_-;_-* 
""-""??_-;_-@_-"

           Else

Cells(thisRow, 1).NumberFormat = "_-* #,##0% _-;[Red]* (#,##0%)_-;_-* " - "?? 
_-;_-@_-"

           End If
   End If

   Next thisRow

   End Sub
```

Comment: Values displayed with % might be number with special formating. Test `Cell(...).Text` to check the displayed value.